# How can I style the borders of my UITableView? I would like them rounded and a little bit beveled

Tags: ios

How can I style the borders of my UITableView? I would like them rounded and a little bit beveled.

In the screenshot you can see the table view Tags and the UITextField Format (with the correct style).

[image]

UITableView background:

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [tagsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Patrick if you want corners of `UITableView` rounded as `UITextField` then you can use `group table` view by changing style of `UITableView` `Plain` to `Group`.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've changed style but I still have the gray background around the table which I don't really like. (See screenshot). Is there a way to remove such background ?

Comment: you can set background color to clear color - [self.tblView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: It doesn't work. See my code in the question. The table is not nil when the method is invoked.

Comment: Nevermind I've solved from interface builder: setting background alpha to 0

Answer (score 0):

Either use the `UITableViewStyleGrouped` or, if you need to customize a bit more, you can use each the cell's `CALayer` (or their contentView's `CALayer`?) to add rounded corners:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.f;
...
```

Of course, don't forget to add QuartzCore.framework to your project if you choose this solution.

*Note that you can apply the exact same principle for your `UITextField` to add rounded corners to it (instead of the solution you have used for your `UITextField` already, whatever it is)*